# Can Swift Share Login Details From Associated Site?

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, autofill

I have an app that associates with a website. The website allows logins and registration, and the app allows the user to connect to the site's backend services.

I am sure this is doable, but haven't been able to figure exactly what to ask for: I want the user to be able to have their password autofilled in the app, so the app can connect to the site (via basic authentication).

How do I do this? Pointers to documentation and a tutorial would be great.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill

Comment: excellent. Not sure why I couldn't find that, but thanks.